# Access the results from a previously executed query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a nested relationship and I would like to filter them, using the result that comes from the first query run by Eloquent.

My Eloquent query is:

```
$entry = Entry::with([
            'products.unit',
            'products.area'
        ])->find($id);
```

The query log shows me that Eloquent runs this query first:
`select * from entry where entry.deleted_at is null and entry.id = ? limit 1`

And I would like to use its result in this second query, also run by Eloquent:

```
select area.*, 
area_product.product_id, area_product.quota as pivot_quota,
area_product.month as pivot_month 
from area inner join area_product 
on area.id = area_product.area_id 
where area.deleted_at is null and area_product.product_id in (?)
```

I would like to put a constraint inside it using the `month` value that comes from the **first query**.

Is there a way to do it using Eloquent?

I was thinking in something like this:

```
$entry = Entry::with([
             'products.unit',
             'products.area' => function ($q) {
               // using month here!
             }
         ])->find($id);
```

Comment: Can you write the raw SQL you are expecting?

Comment: As Eloquent does 2 queries (at least), the first one would be : `select * from entry where entry.deleted_at is null and entry.id = ? limit 1`. Maybe the result of this query is stored somewhere.

The query that I'm expecting would be: 

`select area.*, 
area_product.product_id, area_product.quota as pivot_quota,
area_product.month as pivot_month 
from area inner join area_product 
on area.id = area_product.area_id 
where area.deleted_at is null and area_product.product_id in (?) and area_product.month = ?`